# How to keep the form data persistent and display for a user all the time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, forms

How can I make the user submit the form, store it in MYSQL DB and then display the same submitted data in the form field?

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname">Last Name*</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" value="" autocomplete="nope" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email*</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value=""  autocomplete="nope"required />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phone">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" value="" autocomplete="nope" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Below script is used to save into MSQL database

```
function post() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

  if(firstname && lastname && email && phone) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'profile.php',
      data: {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone
      },
      success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Profile updated successfully";
      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```

Any similar example link would be great!

Now my question/problem/process is:

1. To save the form data into MYSQL DB (this I have already done).
2. How do I still display the form data of that specific user in the input field each time the user login? (To be done)

Kindly help me as I am trying since last 3 days for a solution and have used so many approaches available on the internet and nothing has worked so far. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to start learning php. There are many issues until the database!. In addition, there are hundreds of examples on the site.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file, you need to return the row and in your AJAX success function display data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every time when there is a user login, you should check the `user Id`(or anything that can verify this user) according to the data in database.
2. And by this `user id` you can get the data of this user by `php file`.
3. And the you can get the information show through `ajax` form `php file`.